# How to define systemd "ConsistsOf" relationship

Tags: systemd

I am creating a package `foo` which launches/closes upstream package `bar`. The relationship should be:

- When you start foo, also start bar.
- When to you stop/reload foo, also stop/reload bar.
- `bar` may be started, stopped or reloaded without affecting `foo`

If `/lib/systemd/system/bar.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Bar

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sleep infinity
Restart=on-failure
```

Then then "normal" solution would be to add `WantedBy` and `PartOf` relationships to `bar`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Bar
PartOf=foo.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sleep infinity
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=foo.service
```

However, `bar` is an upstream package and I think it's not quite right to force `bar` to be aware of `foo`, or to patch `bar`.

I thought a perfect solution would be to create `foo.service` like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo
Wants=bar.service
ConsistsOf=bar.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

However my journalctl says:

> Unknown lvalue 'ConsistsOf' in section 'Unit'

and [man pages](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) say:

> When PartOf=b.service is used on a.service, this dependency will show as ConsistsOf=a.service in property listing of b.service. **ConsistsOf= dependency cannot be specified directly.**

I'm not sure *why* `ConsistsOf=` cannot be specified directly, but is there an alternative that I didn't consider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The appropriate way to modify upstream/external bar.service to include a `PartOf=` relationship to another unit is to use a "drop-in" override config, which is a systemd feature allowing you to modify existing units without having to touch the original files.

From [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) man page:

> Along with a unit file `foo.service`, a "drop-in" directory `foo.service.d/` may exist. All files with the suffix "`.conf`" from this directory will be parsed after the unit file itself is parsed. This is useful to alter or add configuration settings for a unit, without having to modify unit files.

In your particular case, you should create a drop-in such as `/etc/systemd/system/bar.service.d/partof-foo.conf`, with contents:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=foo.service
```

(The name `partof-foo.conf` is just a suggestion, anything with a `.conf` suffix should work.)

Then reload the daemon with `systemctl daemon-reload`.

After that is done, you can inspect the unit with `systemctl cat bar`, which will neatly show the override is being taken into account. Also, now, `systemctl show foo` will show a `ConsistsOf=` relationship to `bar.service` and the effects of that relationship will follow (stopping `foo` will cause `bar` to stop.)

For the second part (`foo` having `Wants=bar.service`), I suggest adding that directive directly to `foo.service` instead of using an `[Install]` stanza in an "drop-in" for `bar.service`.

For one, the `[Install]` section would have to be activated with a `systemctl enable bar` command, so in a way it's harder to maintain. (Also, I've seen bugs where `[Install]` from a "drop-in" is not respected. I believe these have been fixed, but might still exist in your distro's version of systemd.)

Furthermore, you might want to use a stronger `Requires=` relationship, rather than `Wants=`, since that will make `foo.service` fail if `bar.service` can't be started. (Consider also adding an ordering dependency, such as `After=bar.service` from `foo.service`, so `foo` will actually wait until `bar` is up before doing its own startup.)

Since `foo.service` is a file you control, simply include it there directly:

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo
Requires=bar.service
After=bar.service
```

That's assuming you'll want the ordering dependency as well, it's safe to omit it if you don't.

That should take care of everything.

Comment: Yes, this works great.